# Django Admin: How to save Page and split tags at the same time?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to save a `Page` instance and split-save its tags at the same time.

This is my code:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(PageCategory, related_name='page_categories', null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=512, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #save first
        self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.title))
        obj = super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #save first
        if obj.id and obj.tags:  #split and assign tags to this page <--ERROR--
            tags = obj.tags.split(',')
            for t in tags:
                atag = t.strip(' ')
                tag, saved = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=atag)
                obj.page_tags.add(tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page, related_name='page_tags')
```

The problem is that I always get this error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about `self.page_tags.add(tag)` instead `obj...` ?

Comment: it works, but why mine is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `obj` by `self`:

```
self.page_tags.add(tag)
```

Because [model save() method don't return any data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py).